# Не определено свойство "WebUser.group_id"

Tags: php, yii

При таком коде

```
print_r(Yii::app()->user);
```

Печатает

```
WebUser Object ( [_model:WebUser:private] => User Object ( [_profile:protected] => Profile Object ( [created_at] => [created_by] => [updated_at] => [updated_by] => [_new:CActiveRecord:private] => [_attributes:CActiveRecord:private] => Array ( [user_id] => 53 [firstname] => Garik [lastname] => test_Lastname [title] => test_title [gender] => male [street] => [zip] => [city] => [country] => [state] => [birthday_hide_year] => 0 [birthday] => 2016-07-01 00:00:00 [about] => [phone_private] => [phone_work] => [mobile] => [fax] => [im_skype] => [im_msn] => [im_icq] => [im_xmpp] => [url] => [url_facebook] => [url_linkedin] => [url_xing] => [url_youtube] => [url_vimeo] => [url_flickr] => [url_myspace] => [url_googleplus] => [url_twitter] => ) [_related:CActiveRecord:private] => Array ( ) [_c:CActiveRecord:private] => [_pk:CActiveRecord:private] => 53 [_alias:CActiveRecord:private] => t [_errors:CModel:private] => Array ( ) [_validators:CModel:private] => [_scenario:CModel:private] => update [_e:CComponent:private] => Array ( [onbeforedelete] => CList Object ( [_d:CList:private] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => ActivityModule [1] => onActiveRecordDelete ) [1] => Array ( [0] => FileModuleEvents [1] => onBeforeHActiveRecordDelete ) ) [_c:CList:private] => 2 [_r:CList:private] => [_e:CComponent:private] => [_m:CComponent:private] => ) ) [_m:CComponent:private] => ) [created_at] => 2016-06-17 10:50:57 [created_by] => 27 [updated_at] => 2016-06-22 09:15:25 [updated_by] => 27 [_new:CActiveRecord:private] => [_attributes:CActiveRecord:private] => Array ( [id] => 53 [guid] => 397272fb-ac4f-4df4-95e7-171b34e85e04 [wall_id] => **[group_id] => 1** [status] => 1 [super_admin] => 1 [username] => test2 [email] => rush@................
```

Мне нужно достать - `[group_id] => 1`.

А при `echo Yii::app()->user->group_id`. Пишет error

> **CException** Не определено свойство "WebUser.group_id"

Comment: Пр всей видимости свойство group_id приватное

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В **class WebUser** добавить функцию

```
public function getGroup()
{
    $user = $this->loadUser(Yii::app()->user->id);
    return $user->group_id;
}
```

Comment: затем в index писать: echo getGroup() ;